# JIRA: how to "archive" ancient backlog

Tags: jira, project-planning, backlog

We have over a thousand old tickets in our Jira, most of which we'll never get to. What are the best ways to hide those from the backlog in a way that we can most easily get them back if we want to?

Ideas:

- give them a label and then complete them as won't fix
- create a special "archive" project and move them in there

Pros & cons to those? Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is this with GreenHopper, and probably using a Scrum board? In that case issues appear based on your board's JQL filter. You could change the filter to add a constraint by date such as "updated < -200d" to excluded issues that haven't been updated in 200 days.

I wouldn't bother moving them to an archive project. Labels can be useful for other things.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest archive it somewhere if you never intend to reuse it.

You can use this project to do so: https://gitlab.com/kaszaq/jiratomkdocs/